# How to dumpValues & Data of a full column in google sheet via google script, in one operation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been handling a big set of Data with automated scripts in google drive. 
These script constantly update some cells in a column through different sheets.

Now here is the problem: Reading and writing in google scripts is **super** long. So I tried to get the column via getValues, dump it in a an array, do my researches and my mods there and write the whole array back to the sheet.

However, this erases the formulas that might have been in the column (*getValues would then return the result of the formula*). Using getFormulas wouldnt give back the values. I could write and read formulas and values, but that would add operations when I'm trying to save time.

How come google doesn't provide a way to directly dump a String content of each cell? Any work around?

A.

Comment: Well, I could find any google specified answer, but I developed a merge function and it's actually fast enough, if anyone needs it :
function dumpColumn(sheet, index){
  var range  = sheet.getRange(1, index, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var arrV =  range.getValues();
  var arrF = range.getFormulas();
  for(i = 0; i<arrF.length; i++){
    if(arrF[i][0] != "")
      arrV[i][0]  =arrF[i][0];   
  }
  return arrV;
}

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could find any google specified answer, but I developed a merge function and it's actually fast enough, if anyone needs it :

```
function dumpColumn(sheet, index){
  var range  = sheet.getRange(1, index, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var arrV =  range.getValues();
  var arrF = range.getFormulas();
  for(i = 0; i<arrF.length; i++){
    if(arrF[i][0] != "")
      arrV[i][0]  =arrF[i][0];   
  }
  return arrV;
}
```